# function php fwrite give a message error

Tags: php, fwrite

Using my webservice I would like to save in a XML file the response that it display to me, but when I'm trying to save this data it displays mze an error:

here is the error I get:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\NEOGETCASH\GESTIONNAIRE\DOSSIERS\creditsafe.php on line 13
```

the code I'm using is there; but I don't know I know that the response is as XML, but id doesn't save in the file I wanted I don't know why, just because it is not a `varchar`.

```
<?php

$wsdl = "https://www.creditsafe.fr/getdata/service/CSFRServices.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$debiteur_siret  = "<xmlrequest><header><username>demo</username><password>**********</password><operation>getcompanyinformation</operation><language>FR</language><country>FR</country><chargereference></chargereference></header><body><package>standard</package><companynumber>40859907400049</companynumber></body>
</xmlrequest> " ;
$o = new stdClass();
$o->requestXmlStr = $debiteur_siret;

$fichier = 
//header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$texte=$client->GetData($o);
echo $texte;
$fp = fopen("tmp/".$_GET['n_doss'].".xml", "w+");
//fwrite($fp, $texte);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message comes from the lines:

```
$texte=$client->GetData($o);
echo $texte;
```

`GetData` does not return a string, but a `stdClass` instead, which can not be converted to a string. `var_dump($texte)` to see what it returns, and echo the appropriate property of the `stdClass`.

**EDIT**: I've looked up the WDSL and checked; the `GetData()` function returns a `GetDataResponse`, which seems to contain a property `GetDataResult` (a string). So the following should work:

```
$texte=$client->GetData($o);
echo $texte->GetDataResult;
```

Comment: thank you verry much for your help.

I have a standard question: in my php page it displays me ï»¿ how can i remove this?

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski That seems like a BOM character. Use a decent PHP editor and save your file as UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

Comment: thnaks for all . It was verry helpfull for me

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Good to hear.